# GeoServer layer is based on PostGIS view, but featureID is random (PK is ignored)

Tags: postgis, geoserver

I have a layer in GeoServer.
It is based on PostGIS view.
It seems that GeoServer generates random featureIDs.
The view has the same columns as the underlying table, including the PK column.
But GeoServer ignores the PK column for layers based on the view.

When I created a layers based on the table itself, GeoServer used PK as featureID.

How do I make GeoServer do the same for a view?

---

I've accepted @iant's answer. SQL I used to create the metadata table is below. After I ran it on the PostGIS DB, I've restarted GeoServer and recreated the layer. It worked.

```
-- http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html#metadata-table-description

CREATE TABLE gt_pk_metadata_table (
  table_schema VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  table_name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  pk_column VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
  pk_column_idx INTEGER,
  pk_policy VARCHAR(32),
  pk_sequence VARCHAR(64),
  unique (table_schema, table_name, pk_column),
  check (pk_policy in ('sequence', 'assigned', 'autoincrement'))
);


INSERT INTO gt_pk_metadata_table(
            table_schema, table_name, pk_column, pk_column_idx, pk_policy, 
            pk_sequence)
    VALUES (
    'public',
    'llsoa',
    'identifier',
    1,
    'assigned',
    null);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to provide a [metadata table](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html#metadata-table-description) which contains the view name and the primary key name. The [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/primarykey.html#using-the-metadata-table-with-views) here explains how.

Comment: Note that the metadata table needs to be indicated to GeoServer. This can be done by setting the value for 'Primary key metadata table' for a specific 'store' via the web UI.

Answer (score 3):

Except for the documented solution [as linked in Ian's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64008/a-geoserver-layer-is-based-on-postgis-view-but-featureid-is-random-pk-is-ignor/64015#64015), one could also [define a new SQL view in GeoServer](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html). If the source view in the database has a column with a stable id, then ticking its "Identifier" checkbox in such view-of-a-view will promote such ids to be stable feature ids, without the use of a table `gt_pk_metadata`:

[image: GeoServer view]

Unlike the `gt_pk_metadata`-solution, the above yields a read-only layer, hence does not support WFS-T.