# WFS from PostGIS view

Tags: qgis, wfs

It is not possible to see in QGIS 3.4 data in WFS service from PostGIS view, it is only possible to see data in services created from tables. Is it not possible to create services from SQL views?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How Geoserver fetches the data that is served should not be a concern to the consumer (Qgis).

If you put the URL that Qgis is [displaying](https://geo.gporellana.gob.ec/geoinfo/datoslibres/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=2.0.0&TYPENAMES=datoslibres:edificio_gadpo&STARTINDEX=0&COUNT=1000000&SRSNAME=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326&OUTPUTFORMAT=application%2Fjson) in a web browser, it has a more meaningful error message:

> Cannot do natural order without a primary key, please add it or
>   specify a manual sort over existing attributes

If you edit the WFS connection property in Qgis, use the URL https://geo.gporellana.gob.ec/geoinfo/datoslibres/wfs?VERSION=2.0.0 and uncheck the box `enable feature paging` then you will be able to display the layer `edificio_GADPO`

[image]

To fix the issue, the Geoserver admin would have to declare a primary key / unique key for the corresponding layer. This [thread](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Anybody-to-confirm-this-WFS-problem-td5381615.html) and [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/64008/a-geoserver-layer-is-based-on-postgis-view-but-featureid-is-random-pk-is-ignor) are worth reading.

Comment: I am review my layer config in geoserver to fix this